# How to use slice() method to split an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, split, slice

The link to this challenge:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-algorithm-scripting/slice-and-splice

I didn’t know how to use splice() so I used the other way to solve the problem.
what did I do wrong here?

```
function frankenSplice(arr1, arr2, n) {
let result = [];
let array1 = arr1.toString();
let array2 = arr2.toString();

for (let i = 0; i<array1.length; i++){
for (let j = 0; j<array2.length; j++){
  if (array1[j] == n){
     return result += array2[j] + array1 + array2.slice(1);
      }
   }
}
   return result;
}

console.log(frankenSplice([1, 2, 3], [4, 5], 1));
```

It should return [4, 1, 2, 3, 5], however my code returns [41,2,3,5].
I wanted to use arr1.split() so there will have a comma between 4 and 1, but it says arr1.split is not a function.

I feel like I am so close to the answer but also feel that my logic could be totally wrong.

Please help, thank you!

Comment: ouch. this is really a one liner if you do it properly. was trying to figure this out less intimidating than googling the splice function?

Answer (score 0):

- First line uses the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to copy the elements of the array into another array, since the original orray should not be altered, according ot the rules.
- The second line uses [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), and starting at the `n`th index, removes `0` items from the array, and then copies all the items from `array1` into it.
- Then we returned the copied array.

> function frankenSplice(arr1, arr2, n) {
>      var a = [...arr2]
>      a.splice(n, 0, ...arr1);
>      return a;
>  }

Comment: `splice` does two things. it adds item to an array and it removes items from an array. it should really be two separate functions, but this is how they did it. the first parameter tells it where to start adding or deleting. the second parameter tells it how many items to delete, after that, all other parameters passed into the function are added to the array at the nth index.

Comment: @yg2160 - i have no idea if you understand it correctly. i know you understand how to copy my answer into a comment.. hopefully the explanation was helpful though.

Comment: Hi, the explanation of splice() method is really clear, I will practice more with it. thanks!